# Additional Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to add a second route to a /privacy page, but it is not working. I get "Cannot GET /privacy.html" error. Any suggestions??

This code does not respond with the privacy.html content

```
app.get('/privacy', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/privacy.html");
});
```

Here is my app.js code

```
//jshuint esversion: 6
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.get('/privacy', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/privacy.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const emailAddress = req.body.emailAddress;

  const data = {
    members: [
      {
        email_address: emailAddress,
        status: "subscribed",
        merge_fields: {
          FNAME: firstName,
          LNAME: lastName
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const url = "https://us.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/bb80b745a8"

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    auth: "meshiaR:93d648-u"
  };

  const request = https.request(url, options, function(response) {

    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
    } else {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
    }

    response.on("data", function(data){
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();
});

// app.post("/privacy", function(req, res){
//   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/privacy.html");
// });

app.post("/failure", function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Server is now running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: You should check the error stack. It tells you where precisely the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieve this kind of tasks.

```
var path = require('path');

app.get('/privacy', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/privacy.html'));
});
```

BTW, check your `privacy.html` is available in correct path.

Comment: I fixed the issue. I set the href in the signup.html link as privacy.html instead of /privacy. Thank you for providing me with a solution.